# Webcam and SMC problems

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, webcam

Whenever I open up FaceTime/Photo Booth/Discord etc., they come up with an error that my (internal) webcam cannot detected. The way I fix this is to reset the SMC , which does work but only for a few minutes, and then we are back to square one.
I have tried `sudo killall VDCAssistant` and `sudo killall VDCAssistant` to no avail.
I am running macOS Mojave, 10.14.3 on a mid-2012 MacBook Air[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: External webcam? Make & model? Internal webcam? What version of macOS?

Comment: See my newly edited post

Answer (score 1):

Try this: quit all apps attempting to use the camera, Finder -> Utilities -> Terminal (you'll likely be asked for your password, this is normal):

```
sudo killall VDCAssistant
sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant
```

…and reopen a camera app. I had an old MacBook Pro with a twitchy camera, and this solved it.

Comment: I've tried this